# Test method with param Action<T> with Nunit and Moq c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm using c#, Nunit and Moq and I want to test a method like the Remove() method, that call another method with an Action<> parameter.

```
public class Db
{
    private readonly IMessageWrapper _messageWrapper;
    private readonly IProvider _provider;

    public Db(IMessageWrapper messageWrapper, IProvider provider)
    {
        _messageWrapper = messageWrapper;
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void Remove()
    {
      Execute(transaction => 
      {
         // Do something

         // method to verify with unit test
         _messageWrapper.SendData();
      });
    }

    private void Execute(Action<SqlTransaction> action)
    {
       _provider.ExecuteAction(action);
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
public class DbTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Remove_Should_SendData()
    {
        //... create IMessageWrapper mock and IProvider mock...
        var db = new Db(messageWrapperMock.Object, provider.Object);
        
        provider.Setup(p => p.ExecuteAction(It.IsAny<Action<SqlTransaction>>));

        db.Remove();
        
        messageWrapperMock.Verify(m => m.SendData(), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. The unit test doesn't reach the _messageWrapper.SendData();

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `setup` without any code - that method does nothing, but you need it to call your action.
Try this:

```cs
provider.Setup(p => p.ExecuteAction(It.IsAny<Action<SqlTransaction>>()))
  .Callback<Action<SqlTransaction>>(c => c(null));
```

Comment: @juharr It's an action that takes `SqlTransaction` parameter. You mistaken it for Func<SqlTransaction>